# Printing a List Recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I'm trying to print the data in each Node in a Linked List using recursion, but I'm getting out of bounds errors, so I think something's wrong with my recursive function.

Here's the header file:

```
class List
{
public:
    void print(std::ostream &out) const {}
private:
    Node *head;
    void printList(std::ostream&, const Node*) const;
}
```

Basically, I'm calling the private helper function from the public `print` function. Here's the code for the two functions:

```
void List::print(std::ostream& out) const
{
    printList(out, head);
}

void List::printList(std::ostream& out, const Node* n) const
{
    if(n->next == NULL) {
        out << n->data << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    out << n->data << std::endl;

    printList(out, n->next);
}
```

I think the problem lies within my if block because I need to stop if there is no next Node, but also print the data in the current Node before returning, but since I already call `n->next` at the end in `printList(out, n->next)`, do I need to do it in my if block?

Is there a better way to do this recursively? Does the code work for anyone else? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I would rather write `void List::printList(std::ostream& out, const Node* n) const
{
    if(n == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    out << n->data << std::endl;

    printList(out, n->next);
}` for simplicity sake.

Comment: Are you sure you initialize the nodes `next` pointer to a null pointer when a node is created? Or at least make sure the `next` pointer of the last node in the list is a null pointer?

Comment: Is `n->next` properly being set to a `nullptr` in the base case? Or is it a random, uninitialized, address?

Comment: What a purpose to print a list recursively? You are at risk to overflow the stack with no obvious benefit.

Comment: Also, what happens if the list is empty, and `head` is a null pointer?

Comment: Lastly, you say you get "out of bounds errors", can you please elaborate on that? How do you know you are "out of bounds"? What kind of errors do you get? Crashes? Unexpected output? Stack overflows? Please be specific.  Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @WitchKing17  Is head a data member of the class List?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes. Head is a Node* data member of the List class. It is initialized to nullptr when a List is created, and subsequent Nodes are added onto the list making it not be null anymore.

Comment: @RyanP `n->next` pulls from the pointer that gets passed in, which is `head`. `head` gets initialized to NULL in the constructor, when there are no nodes. As more nodes are added in, the List subsequently grows. I forgot to include the data members.

Comment: This will just be optimized into an iteration by your compiler anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the condition inside `if()`. You should check whether current node is `NULL` or not instead of next node.

```
void List::printList(std::ostream& out, const Node* n) const { 
    if(n == NULL) { 
        return; 
    } 
    out << n->data << std::endl; 
    printList(out, n->next); 
}
```

Comment: That helped. That actually makes more sense, ha! Thanks!